# C++ Builder 10.3 Rio - Testframework

Tags: c++builder, test-framework, c++builder-10.3-rio

It seems that C++ builder 10.3. comes with a new `testframework.hpp`. The class `Assert` does not exist any longer.

Can anyone tell me how to use this new framework?

I am desperate because I wrote a lot of code and obviously Rio is not really compatible.

for example the following code line, written in Builder 10.2.3,  doesn't work any longer:

```
Dunitx.Testframework::Assert::IsTrue (result == true);
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution in the testframework.hpp - file. The usage is now a lot easier but you will have to know how to handle it. The description in the embaracdero help system is wrong and should be corrected.

Comment: The Testframework.hpp file you found is for DUnit. You need Dunitx.Testframework.hpp. **See above how to obtain it**. DUnit and DunitX are similar but incompatible test frameworks. You obviously need DUnitX, and the help you found if for DUnitX too, not for the older DUnit.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have found the *TestFramework.hpp* for **DUnit**. But it is obvious your code was using **DUnitX** before. These are similar but *incompatible* test frameworks.

To get the *Dunitx.Testframework.hpp* you need, simply add *DUnitX.TestFramework.pas* to your C++Builder test project (add it in the project manager) and completely re-build your project. The Pascal compiler will generate the necessary *.hpp* file for you.

---

**But before you do all that, you may want to copy your project to a new folder**, and load it from there, just to be sure. That way, the older project will not be modified. Be sure to update all your paths in the project manager and C++ library settings too, if necessary.

---

If you think DUnit is easier to use (I certainly do), then keep on using that. But you will have to rewrite some parts of your tests. More info can be found in the Delphi help files (and [on the web counterpart](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Rio/en/DUnit_Overview)) and on [the DUnit website](http://dunit.sourceforge.net/).

**DUnit** was the former test framework for Delphi (hence the D), but at some time in the past, it was replaced by the more modern **DUnitX**. But that uses some Delphi features (like Delphi attributes) that make it harder to use in C++Builder. DUnit is still part of the RAD Studio installation.